# tortoiseSVN where to find the physical location of it's ignore list (win10)

Tags: tortoisesvn, ignore, svnignore

As the caption states - where is the physical location of tortoises' ignore list?

(i'm not asking how to (un-)ignore files or folders)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. TSVN (Subversion per se) doesn't have|use files for this task. Ignore-pattern is ordinary *svn-property* (of files|folders **in repository**)
2. Default global runtime settings for ignore-patterns *can be* defined in `Subversion\config` file: `[miscellany]` section, `global-ignores` key